# MySQL if then/ case statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case-statement

there!
I'm writing mysql script in mySQl Front 4.1.
I have problem with if then, case statements.

I have next code:

```
set @prodID = -1;
select @prodID = productID
from partid_to_productid 
where PartID= 8;


case @prodID
 WHEN NULL then select 0;
 else select 3;
 end case
```

Front doesn't want to execute it. Why?
Can someone explain me what is wrong here?

Comment: the anwser is what @Michel says or: consider that CASE is an operator (it returns one value) but it do not control flow, nor excutes statments (as you put SELECTs). if you need flow control replace with IFs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SELECT` goes outside the `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
  CASE @prodID 
    WHEN NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 3
  END;
```

Actually, that's not returning 0 for me as I expect when testing. Instead try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @prodID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 3 END;
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to write in mysql something like this 
  `if @partID is null then 
   insert into partid_to_productid
   (value1, value2)`